# "Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Optional'". Problems with the installation of Andorid Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to the forum, so I hope I don't violate any rules I'm not aware of. I recently tried reinstalling Android Studio and it seemed like there was no problem. Instead every time I start a new project I get this error:

```
Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Optional'.
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

that I don't know how to solve. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software but the problem persists. Anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem as you, and I solved it by redoing the project from the beginning and connecting the graphic elements to the phone screen in the activity.xml file, or by clicking on the circles inherent to the element taken into consideration and bringing the arrows towards the screen (connecting them)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).