# Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Optional'. This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i try to make my first project, compound from a button and a text, when i try to build i have this type of problem:

Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Optional'.
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
the problem arose after inserting the button.
Thank you

I solved:
I solved it by redoing the project from the beginning and connecting the graphic elements to the phone screen in the activity.xml file, or by clicking on the circles inherent to the element taken into consideration and bringing the arrows towards the screen (connecting them)

Comment: Same question as asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018582

Comment: I suggest that you do what it suggests.  File a bug report.